Expected Number of Distinct Prime Factors: Infinite vs Finite Support
Consider the uniform distribution on $1,2,\ldots,n$; by the Erdos-Kac Central Limit Theorem, its expected number of distinct prime factors is asymptotically $\log \log n$, which tends to $\infty$ (its variance is also $\log \log n$).
On the other hand, if we have a distribution with infinite support, such as the Zeta(s) distribution, then its expected number of distinct prime factors is finite and equal to $\sum_{p} \frac{1}{p^s}$, where the sum is over all primes $p$, and variance $\sum_{p} \frac{1}{p^s}-\sum_{p} \frac{1}{p^{2s}}$; these sums are finite when $s>1$.
Is it true in general: If I have a variable on $\mathbb{N}$, are the mean and variance of the number of distinct prime factors always finite?

The answer is no. Using $p_j$ to denote the $j$th prime, one counterexample (for the mean) is the random variable that, for each $k\ge1$, takes the value $p_1p_2\cdots p_{2^k}$ with probability $2^{-k}$.
